# How to transfer a file from one directory to another that is the newest file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to transfer a file from one directory to another that is the current and latest file in that folder, however I cannot use Robocopy to do this, since it fails when the server is logged out.  Is there another way I can do this in Vb.net?

Thank you.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Finding the file, or transferring it? System.IO should have all you need....

Comment: I don't know how to transfer and find the newest file?  I don't know how to write the code using System.IO

Comment: Start with `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`.  You can then sort the results to get the newest file and then call `MoveTo` on the `FileInfo` object.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `File.Copy(Source,Destination,Overwrite?)` to overwrite the file with a newer one, or

```
If File.Exists(destination) Then File.Delete(destination);
' Move the file.
File.Move(source, destination);
```

to move the file... I pesonally prefer:

```
File.Copy(Source,Destination,true)
File.Delete(Source)
```

To move the file and overwrite it if it exists :)... less code

Here's the code to move the latest file to another directory

```
Dim SourceDirectory As String = "C:\sourcedirectory\"
Dim SaveDirectory As String = "C:\targetdirectory\"
Dim LatestFile as IO.FileInfo = Nothing

'Let's scan the directory and iterate through each file...
Dim DirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(SourceDirectory)
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In DirInfo.GetFiles()
    If LatestFile Is Nothing Then
        'This is the first time we run any permutations, so let's assign this file as "the latest" until we find one that's newer 
        LatestFile = file
    ElseIf file.CreationTime > LatestFile.CreationTime Then
        'Changes the "Latest file" if this file was created after the previous one.
        'You can also change the check to .LastAccessTime and .LastWriteTime depending on how you want to define "the newest"...
        LatestFile = file
    End If
 Next
 'Now we move the file, but first, check to see if we actually did find any file in the source directory
If NewestFile IsNot Nothing Then
    NewestFile.CopyTo(SaveDirectory & NewestFile.Name,true) 'will copy and overwrite existing file
    'Now we can delete the old one
    NewestFile.Delete()
Else
    'Could not find the newest file, or directory might be empty...
End If
'Done!
```

Hope that Helps